# Flight search engine for specific date for outbound flight and undefined date for return flight?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-search-engines

On a specific date, I have to fly from A to B. Using various flight search engines, it turned out that the cheapest possibility is to buy a return ticket. Now the problem is, the search engines I know do not allow to search for the cheapest flight with a the first flight on a specific date and the second flight on a random (the cheapest) day. I want to do this, because I won't use the second flighty anyway. So is there any search engines that allows me to search flights like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.net)

Just choose the Whole Month as departure and arrival date. You will be presented with a graphic in which you can pick the departure date, the arrival calendar will update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, however skyscanner does not show me direct flights that I could find with other search engines.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: after you do the search look at the filters in the top bar (over the graphic). There should be a "direct flight" filter.

Comment: Exactly that is the problem ;)

Comment: @Roflcoptr: got you now :-)

Comment: we could try to help more if you provide more information like: A and B actual airports, desidered departure date and site you tried :-)

Comment: Zürich to Vancouver, 10.08.2012, tried sites: skyscanner, kayak.com, itasoftware, swiss.com